# Flutter not found when developing plugin for Android

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

I forked a plugin with the intent to make an update to use the embedding v2 for Android. But when I opened the android folder on Android Studio it does not find Flutter. It fails to import these classes:

```kotlin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
```

[image]

Is there anything I am missing to edit the Android part of a Flutter plugin?

This is the plugin I am trying to update: https://github.com/lslv1243/launch_review

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It worked for me when I did the next steps (assuming that Dart and Flutter plugins are configured in the Android Studio Preferences properly):

1. Close all the projects up until you see the "welcome to Android Studio" window with recent projects list and a set of options in the center
2. Select "Open existing Android Studio project"
3. Select the file `plugin/example/android/build.gradle`

Comment: But why it's working to open it from plugin/example/android/build.gradle and not working from plugin/android/build.gradle ?

Comment: You saved me a lot of time and nerves. Thank you! Opening an example projects's build.gradle really did help

Comment: this don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 9):

You should open the project in android studio from the example/android location.

Answer (score 8):

It turned out to be a known error: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19830. You can find different solutions and general discussion of the problem there.

Provided solutions did not help in my case. What had worked out is this one (by [@incloudss](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19830#issuecomment-854639146)):

> For everyone who still struggles with that problem, ignore the official documentation, and do not open android project the way they describe it there.
>
> Instead:
>
> 1. Open the main flutter project.
> 2. Go to Tools -> Flutter -> Open For Editing In Android Studio(yes, it doesn't >make sense because we are already in AS, but it works).

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar situation when I imported an android project from the plug-in module of my Flutter project. That means, My Flutter project has an android folder at the root directory of the project, and another android directory inside the module I imported as a plug-in. If I try to open that module with the android studio it will not detect "**io.flutter.plugin.common**" packages.Because it missing the 'flutter.jar' library.

So what I did was, I Just added the flutter.jar path to dependency,

```
implementation files('/Users/username/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/flutter.jar')
```

here I choose 'android-arm64-release' because I am using M1 chip macbook.

Now i can edit the android module of the plugin project.But to run the flutter project  i have to comment out the flutter.jar dependency and sync again before run, otherwise it will show conflict errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Flutter SDK https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk

Then in Android Studio, go to settings>plugins, and install the Flutter and Dart plugins.

Then check whether you have provided you SDK path at Settings> Language & Frameworks > Flutter

Comment: I do have these installed

Comment: I am using mac and it is called "Preferences" instead of "Settings". But when I go to "Languages & Frameworks" I don't have an option called "Flutter". I do have installed both Flutter and Dart plugins in my Android Studio. Do you know what could be missing?

Comment: Your response is correct. My Dart version was incompatible with the Android Studio version. I updated it and it is working now. I will just check if the error goes away.

Comment: I provided the SDK path https://i.ibb.co/xCS2NgM/Captura-de-Tela-2020-06-03-a-s-12-00-31.png but the error did not go away https://i.ibb.co/qNzjS4k/Captura-de-Tela-2020-06-03-a-s-12-00-53.png

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a **flutter** plugin project. (my as version is Android Studio Electric Eel | `2022.1.1 Patch 2`)

like this `flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin  plugin_himan --platforms=ios,android,linux,windows,macos --android-language=java --ios-language=objc`

- in android studio, open Project Structure
- Select Project Settings-Modules, then you can see plugin_himan and plugin_himan_android
- select Dependencies, Module SDK chose one you need
- click + button, chose **Jars** or Directories (copy your flutter_embedding_debug.jar path)

Now you can direct use flutter package or class, in `plugin_himain/android` project. How to get `flutter_embedding_debug.jar`.

1. build flutter engine source
2. or use gradle like this compileOnly `io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-tag`, in [**download**](http://download.flutter.io/) get `ETag` replace tag in `io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-tag`

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying to resolve this issue, what fixed it for me was:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19830#issuecomment-1688736003

It turns out, you have to build the android app first in the example directory.

1. Call `flutter build apk --config-only` in the `<your_plugin>/example/android`. (Take note of the `example` directory).
2. Finally, open the `<your_plugin>/example/android` in Android Studio (Still in the `example` directory).

It should open two Android modules:`<your_plugin>/example/android` and `<your_plugin>/android`.